# Single line UILabel - wrong baseline position

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have wrong vertical baseline position in a custom UILabel subclass with `numberOfLines = 1` (red line shows baseline):

[image]

but it works fine in case of `numberOfLines = 0` or other positive value:

[image]

This custom label has:

- attributed text,
- overridden `textRect(forBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)`.

In overridden method I compensate text clipping, which occurs because line height value is used to calculate label rendering rect and it's too small for this purpose. Here's the code:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel
{
    var lineHeight: CGFloat!
    
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect
    {
        func snapToScreenScale(_ length: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
        {
            let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
            return ceil(length * scale) / scale
        }
        
        func compensation() -> CGFloat
        {
            // text inside line area is attached to bottom and may be clipped at top
            // so to compensate clipping we should add difference between required and original line heights
            let topCompensation = max(
                0,
                snapToScreenScale(
                    font.lineHeight - lineHeight
                )
            )
            
            // lines of text are centered verticaly in label's bounds
            // so to compensate top clipping completely we should add equal extra space at top and bottom
            let compensation = topCompensation * 2
            
            return compensation
        }
        
        var rect = super.textRect(
            forBounds: bounds,
            limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines
        )
        rect.size = .init(
            width: snapToScreenScale(rect.width),
            height: snapToScreenScale(rect.height)
        )
        rect.size.height += compensation()
        
        return rect
    }
}
```

And how label is used:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 32
paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 32

let label = CustomLabel()
label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
label.lineHeight = 32
label.numberOfLines = 1
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Text",
    attributes: [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 32),
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
    ]
)
view.addSubview(label)
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

let baseline = UIView()
baseline.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
view.addSubview(baseline)
baseline.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
baseline.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.firstBaselineAnchor).isActive = true
baseline.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
baseline.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
baseline.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
```

Notice, due to project requirements:

- I can't increase line height,
- I can't always use `numberOfLines = 0`.

Interesting detail: call to `super` in `textRect(forBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)` has side effect; if it's not called, baseline is attached to label's top:

[image]

So, label behaves obviously wrong. Attempt to fix constraints with call to label's methods

```
setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
```

didn't help, tried at different moments (after label init, after rect calculation, after layout).

Tested in iOS 12.0 - 14.5.

Will appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Added workaround. Idea is to set `numberOfLines` to 0, since bug doesn't occur then; and to constrain number of lines I calculate text rect with required number of lines, so extra text doesn't fit in rect and is wrapped.

Code illustrates this approach; notice that this code is just a concept and isn't any reliable or well-designed etc.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel
{
    var lineHeight: CGFloat!
    var requiredNumberOfLines: Int!

    override var numberOfLines: Int
    {
        get
        {
            return requiredNumberOfLines
        }
        set
        {
            requiredNumberOfLines = newValue
            super.numberOfLines = 0 // override to prevent bug with incorrect baseline position
        }
    }
    
    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect
    {
        func snapToScreenScale(_ length: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
        {
            let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
            return ceil(length * scale) / scale
        }
        
        func compensation() -> CGFloat
        {
            // text inside line area is attached to bottom and may be clipped at top
            // so to compensate clipping we should add difference between required and original line heights
            let topCompensation = max(
                0,
                snapToScreenScale(
                    font.lineHeight - lineHeight
                )
            )
            
            // lines of text are centered verticaly in label's bounds
            // so to compensate top clipping completely we should add equal extra space at top and bottom
            let compensation = topCompensation * 2
            
            return compensation
        }
        
        var rect = super.textRect(
            forBounds: bounds,
            limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines
        )
        rect.size = .init(
            width: snapToScreenScale(rect.width),
            height: snapToScreenScale(rect.height)
        )
        rect.size.height += compensation()
        
        return rect
    }
}
```